# Remote app won't connect, says "Turn on home sharing"

Tags: ios, appletv, remote.app

After an update installed, none of my iOS devices recognize my Apple TV from the Remote App. They just say "Turn on Home Sharing..."

When I go through the "add remote" wizard, I see a disabled music icon. I can't do anything with it except delete it.

What am I missing?

[image: Remote App with music icon]

Answer (score 1):

I play a song on my phone and then close AirPlay and select Apple TV which wakes the device. This works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue but I lost the physical remote months ago so my only notion is the remote app. So far the only fix I've been able to use is to unplug the Apple TV and plug it back up and connect the remote app while it is rebooting/already on.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Apple TV update seems to have killed its ability to be woken from sleep. A lot of people are reporting this problem. So far, the only fix is to turn on Apple TV using the physical remote and then connect your iOS devices to it. The physical remote (that came with Apple TV) seems to be the only thing that can wake it.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue what I do since my Apple Remote is lost is unplug the Apple TV and when it starts back up I can connect my remote app to the Apple TV no problems....its a pain but its what works till they fix it